# How does dynamic dispatch happen in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I found some code somewhere and decided to spit that out in assembly to try and find the difference.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        void f() const { std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl; }
};

class B {
    public:
        void f() const { std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a ;
    B b ;

    a.f() ;
    b.f() ;
}
```

-

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
    public:
        virtual void f() const = 0 ;
        virtual ~base() {}
};

class A : public base {
    public:
        virtual void f() const { std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public base {
    public:
        virtual void f() const { std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl; }
};

void dispatch(const base & x) {
    x.f();
}

int main() {
    A a ;
    B b ;

    dispatch(a) ;
    dispatch(b) ;
}
```

I was looking at this similar question ([How to tell if a program uses dynamic dispatch by looking at the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995922/how-to-tell-if-a-program-uses-dynamic-dispatch-by-looking-at-the-assembly)) and tried to find that in the assembly, however it is not clear to me.

Here is the diff file for the two programs (http://www.diffchecker.com/b9y0v3ps). Could someone point out where the dynamic dispatch is happening and perhaps explain a bit about what's going on and what the difference is between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the assembly you link to, non-virtual dispatch goes like:

```
53    call _ZNK1A1fEv
```

calling the function directly.

Virtual dispatch goes like:

```
53    mov  EAX, DWORD PTR [EBP - 4]
54    mov  ECX, DWORD PTR [EAX]
56    call DWORD PTR [ECX]
```

loading the address of the vtable from the object, then loading the function address from the vtable, then calling the function indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic dispatch is implemented by means of a virtual function table that has the address of the final overrider for the complete object. The object itself contains a pointer to the appropriate vtable.

In assembly you should be able to recognize that for dynamic dispatch the function to call is *loaded* through the vptr, while in the case of static dispatch the call is resolved to the address of the function directly.